# Make repeated API calls until all results are collected

Tags: php, recursion, foreach, slim

My script is designed with the following intention :

1. I visit the route `/postman-test-route`
2. It makes an API call to `https://pro-sitemaps.com/api/` with some headers and parameters
3. Each API result shows a maximum 20-entries
4. When the result is shown, I iterate the result and count the entries. If `entries == 20`, then another API call is made, but change the `'from'` parameters from `0` to `20`, then `40` then `60` etc. until a batch of entries is LESS than `20`.

The trouble is that the code only runs once. The code looks like this:

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'],'/postman-test-route', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    function getPROsitemapsEntries($total_from)
    {
        $client = new Client([
            'sink' => 'C:\Users\****\Desktop\temp.txt'
        ]);

        $r = $client->request('POST', 'https://pro-sitemaps.com/api/', [
            'form_params' => [
                'api_key' => 'ps_UmTvDUda.***************',
                'method' => 'site_history',
                'site_id' => 3845****,
                'from' => $total_from, // From the entity's ID, can run a foreach for every 20 entries. Keep a counter on result, if less than 20 then continue, otherwise die.
            ]
        ]);
        return $r;
    }

    $function_call =   getPROsitemapsEntries(0);
    $responseData = json_decode($function_call->getBody(), true);

    $i = 0;
    $items = array(); // ALL entries should be saved here. 
    foreach ($responseData['result']['entries'] as $entries) {
        $items[] = $entries;
        $i++;
    }

    // Here it should call the API again with 'from' = 20, then 40, then 60
    if ($i > 20) {
        getPROsitemapsEntries($i);
    } else {
        die;
    }
```

So as you can see this code:

```
if ($i > 20) {
    getPROsitemapsEntries($i);
} else {
    die;
}
```

I thought this would call the API again and inside foreach new entries should be saved (not override).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are actually calling the API again, you're just not iterating over the results.

```
$shouldProcess = true;
$searchIndex = 0;
$items = [];
while ($shouldProcess) {
    $processedThisLoop = 0;
    $function_call = getPROsitemapsEntries($searchIndex);
    $responseData = json_decode($function_call->getBody(), true);

    foreach($responseData['result']['entries'] as $entries) {
        $items[] = $entries;
        $searchIndex++;
        $processedThisLoop++;
    }

    if($processedThisLoop == 0) {
        // Didn't find any so stop the loop
        $shouldProcess = false;
    }
}

var_dump($items);
```

In the code above we are keeping track of the total amount of entries we have processed in `$searchIndex`. This will allow us to keep getting new items instead of the old ones.

`$shouldProcess` is a `bool` that will dictate if we should keep trying to get new entries from the API.

`$items` is an array that will hold all entries from the API.

`$processedThisLoop` contains the amount of entries that we have processed in this loop, i.e. did this request to the API have any entries to process? If it didn't, then set `$shouldProcess` to false and this will stop the `while` loop.

Comment: Looks like the prosess takes to long: message: "The system was halted because an error occurred. code: 1, message: The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum execution time.",

Comment: Localhost, im using Guzzle with hosting in Google App Engine

Comment: There is a php configuration option called [max_execution_time](https://www.simplified.guide/php/increase-max-execution-time) which defaults to 30 seconds. If you are getting the error locally you will need to update it. If the error is on Google App Engine I think the maximum execution time is 60 seconds but I'm not sure how to update that. You should raise another question for this issue, as it is no longer in scope of this one.

Comment: max_execution_time = 300 worked. Thank you @Jim you did alot for me, even coded it for me also explained how it works. Thank you alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

For more elegant iteration, use a post-test loop. A `do {} while ()` construct will ensure that the API will be called at least once, then only break at the end of each iteration if there are no results or if the number of results is not divisible by 20.

Use `array_push()` with the spread operator to unpack each batch of results into your result array. The seldom enjoyed native behavior of `array_push()` will return its new count -- this spares the need for an extra `count()` call on each iteration.

Code: ([Mock Demo](https://3v4l.org/sW7fJ))

```
$count = 0;
$items = [];
do {
    $response = json_decode(getPROsitemapsEntries($count)->getBody(), true);
    $count = array_push($items, ...$response['result']['entries']);
} while ($count && $count % 20 === 0);
var_export($items);
```

<sub>The above snippet is strictly designed for an API call which returns a maximum of 20 rows per call and is not designed for APIs with unlimited response volumes.</sub>